# AoCG2021 Day 17: Langton's Hexa-Virus

Tags: code-golf, sequence, hexagonal-grid

The story continues from [AoC2017 Day 22](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/22), Part 2.

---

The damn virus that was infecting a grid computing cluster now has jumped to a *hexagonal* computing cluster! In this cluster, the computers are connected in the honeycomb-like shape, and each computer has three neighbors.

```
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  .x  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  ..
```

Initially, the cluster is completely clean, and the virus is at `x`, facing east. At each tick, the virus moves in the following manner:

- If the current computer is clean, infect it, turn left (60 degrees), and move forward once (move to the neighboring computer in that direction).
- Otherwise (the current computer is infected), clean it, turn right, and move forward once.

Some initial iterations look like this (generated using [this program](https://tio.run/##jVNdj5swEHz3rxgpqoDG9DC5plcqHvrWh/6ASohKCEwOCTmRw6lUVX57umvz1aqV7sXrmd2dtc1w@Tk8n83hft/hix6r09lUPb5W5jScTXDFZzOIHepeVyZDZ1pdD6hMg@HFGvS6HT5NrG4yX7ambXd6HoRodItLeLJdI1G/WOvWOsoE2rOFpX5YmqfD@FHiPfMuUW8SR4mjS6BrnQbynDp5EmsxqjNcbGeGMPgWcFVoZR2xBA@G7q8awRhIaNPkQRCxlu5dHfYI672KHh7SCG@QslqyqL39r9q7v9WueunCHzlP0m7eiBE5ikRCSaQSBwm@Ol1yXj9IPEl8dOuyV9ygfNxCUlCHTSQtRTKKdBQ1q6cpbjH1p4mPW5zygdIpviK/YJqbPk7xNfkZ0znTYymE/6jT10Qi3DvnuGp@rqbjXMjniQRbyzmLqF/EqShDqChIHxyKJxg7nEw4mXA8F8RqZWZi6lDRzY1ij/OkZWwxltnoHDqyIRb@JpjrVtf22oRjxLb9h/sFdt4MXMVZmr5s2YFj0ZVUZfQPf/tiPoxcR5ZFuJGc7VkW1FEKb9Xv/EiuyNXchP999vmkXCSl8K@@UoooP9QT4n7/DQ); `.` is clean, `*` is infected, `x` is the virus at a clean computer, and `X` is the virus at an infected one):

```
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  .x  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  x.  .
 ..  .*  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  .x  .. 
.  ..  *.  .
 ..  .*  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  x*  .. 
.  ..  *.  .
 ..  .*  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .x  *.  .
 ..  .*  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  *.  .
 ..  x*  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  *.  .
 ..  *X  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  *.  .
 ..  *.  .. 
.  ..  x.  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  *.  .
 ..  *.  .. 
.  ..  *x  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  *.  .
 ..  *.  x. 
.  ..  **  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  *x  .
 ..  *.  *. 
.  ..  **  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  **  .. 
.  .*  X*  .
 ..  *.  *. 
.  ..  **  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  *X  .. 
.  .*  .*  .
 ..  *.  *. 
.  ..  **  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  x.  .
 ..  *.  .. 
.  .*  .*  .
 ..  *.  *. 
.  ..  **  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  .. 

 ..  .x  .. 
.  ..  *.  .
 ..  *.  .. 
.  .*  .*  .
 ..  *.  *. 
.  ..  **  .
 ..  ..  .. 
.  ..  ..  .
 ..  ..  ..
```

A better visualization can be seen [here (pdf)](https://oeis.org/A269757/a269757.pdf).

The number of infected computers at each iteration is [A269757](https://oeis.org/A269757):

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7,
8, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 9,
10, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
18, 17, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 19, 18, 19,
20, 21, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 19, 20, 21,
22, 21, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 23, 22, 21,
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 23, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, ...
```

Your task is to output the sequence. Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules and [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) [I/O methods](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) apply. (0-based and 1-based indexing allowed.) The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 67 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=d=>n--?g(d+(g[t=d*2/3&3,[x+=--t%2,y+=--t%2]]^=2)-1):d)(x=y=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcbRDoIgFADQX/GlvDeBFN/aLq3vYNaYKKMZOGRNv55eOk/nbb5mG5NfMw/RTmWmEkiBI0sqcH53YBtwOpO9yGt/7pneG@I8nyQ7/hmGJ0nkHd4swk4HtVjGGLa4TGKJDrQQ4pGSOaBrWxzEx6wAL1Z5rEhVM3jEpq6x/AA)

Remove all spaces from OP's example, we got:

```javascript
......
......
......
......
...x..
......
......
......
......

......
......
......
...x..
...*..
......
......
......
......

......
......
...x..
...*..
...*..
......
......
......
......

......
......
..x*..
...*..
...*..
......
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..x*..
...*..
......
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..**..
..x*..
......
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..**..
..*X..
......
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..**..
..*...
...x..
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..**..
..*...
...*x.
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..**..
..*.x.
...**.
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..**x.
..*.*.
...**.
......
......
......

......
......
..**..
..*X*.
..*.*.
...**.
......
......
......

......
......
..*X..
..*.*.
..*.*.
...**.
......
......
......

......
...x..
..*...
..*.*.
..*.*.
...**.
......
......
......

...x..
...*..
..*...
..*.*.
..*.*.
...**.
......
......
......
```

And you will find out the pattern: "Up, Up, Left, Down, Down, Right". That's how \$ \lfloor \frac{2}{3}\cdot d \rfloor \$ comes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>79</strike>, <strike>74</strike> (@xnor), 61 bytes (@tsh)

```python
x={0}
p=c=0
while[print(c)]:c=len(x);p+=1j**(c*2//3&3);x^={p}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8K22qCWq8A22daAqzwjMyc1uqAoM69EI1kz1irZNic1T6NC07pA29YwS0tLI1nLSF/fWM1Y07oizra6oPb/fwA)

##### Older versions

```python
x={2}
p=c=0
while[print(c)]:x^={p};c+=x>{p}or-1;p+=1j**(c*2//3)*(1j-c%3%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8K22qiWq8A22daAqzwjMyc1uqAoM69EI1kz1qoizra6oNY6Wdu2wg7IyC/SNbQu0LY1zNLS0kjWMtLXN9bU0jDM0k1WNVY10vz/HwA)

```python
x={*()}
p=c=0
while[print(c)]:x^={p};c+=(x>={p})or-1;p+=1j**(c*2//3)*(1j-c%3%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbBCkBAEADQu//YmplNrL3R@BFxmRSb7CRlJd@@8k5P73OJu8858UOAb6EsXBfXsm7zoMe6nyA4tmniR99OLEPq/2I8StepZReIQKipKo8ELpRivGkw5w8)

set `x` holds points infected,
`p` is current position and `c` is current infection count.
Note that current heading needn't be tracked because it can be inferred from `c%6`.

Coordinates are complex numbers. It would be desirable to base them on actual geometry but that has numerical problems. <strike>Which is why we use integer coordinates, i.e. an orthogonal grid with only one diagonal direction connected.</strike> Instead, we deform the grid by "squeezing out" the unreachable hexagon centres resulting in a square grid (with some connections missing), see picture: hat tip to @tsh for that.

[image]

Comment: You can cut the parens around `x>={p}`. For initializing the set `x`, it looks like it's fine if starts with some element like `x={()}`; maybe `x={0}` could be made to work with rearranging the loop.

Comment: Thx, @xnor. Actually, `2` is unreachable and also allows us to drop the `=` from `>=`.

Comment: I didn't understand your formula. But maybe `x=set()` `p=c=0` `while[print(c)]:x^={p};c=len(x);p+=1j**(c*2//3)*(1j-c%3%2)` is 72 bytes.

Comment: Using my formula in my JS post would be 66 bytes: `x=set();p=0` `while[print(len(x))]:x^={p};p+=1j**(233>>len(x)%6*2&3)`. `&3` is not optional due to floating point errors.

Comment: @tsh at long last I understand what you are doing! But can't you simplify to `1j**(len(x)*2//3&3)`?

Comment: @loopywalt Yes. And I understand your formula finally...

Comment: I'm curious how the new version works using only orthogonal moves. It's very concise!

Comment: @xnor It's all tsh's idea, really; but I've added a picture to the post.

Comment: @xnor you may get it by simply remove all spaces in the example grids of OP’s post.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```
ＦＮ«⊞υＬＫＡＰ⎇℅ＫＫψ*Ｍ✳÷×⁴ＬＫＡ³»⎚Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY@xjsIwDIZn@hQWk4PCcDokhk6oXZDgYOAFcq1LLdIUOQkSQvfsIb1bDhYP/n59/t30RprR2JS6UQC37hrDVxy@SVApeBSzY/Q9Rg07cufQ45HosrE2Q1UWM@4AD9KyM/aXTGvYm@vGez67bGuEBnKBWg2dKoGsp3@8pleerwm7gDULNYHHyRBqvnFLeOKBPK6mnIZPlceJxBm5vxfQcNcwX8yngj9FZcnkV8riz1wZHzBmlNL6Iy1v9gk) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` members of the sequence. Edit: Saved 6 bytes using @loopywait's observation that the direction can be inferred from the infection count. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ«
```

Input `n` and loop that many times.

```
⊞υＬＫＡ
```

Save the number of infected computers at this step.

```
Ｐ⎇℅ＫＫψ*
```

Flip the current computer between uninfected and infected.

```
Ｍ✳÷×⁴ＬＫＡ³
```

Move in a hexagonal pattern on an octagonal grid, based on the number of infected computers. Note that the exact orientation of the grid is not significant, so north west and south east are actually represented by north and south.

```
»⎚Ｉυ
```

Output the gathered list of infected computer counts.

Here's a version that you can run locally to animate the progress of infection (the virus itself is not shown):

```
ＲＦφφ«Ｐ⎇℅ＫＫψ*Ｍ✳÷⊕×⁴ＬＫＡ³
```

Outputs the first 1,000 steps (the first `φ` is the animation speed, the second the number of steps). Replace the `Ｆ` with `Ｗ` if you want the program to run indefinitely. The extra `⊕` skews north and south back to north west and south east.

Comment: Right tool for the job :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 78 bytes

```
n->for(i=!p=#a=Map(),n,iferr(mapdelete(a,p),e,mapput(a,p,1));p+=I^(#a*2\3));#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCgIxDAC/Uukl0SzoepTs3YM/WBYCplLQGEJ9f@0e5jBzGJeo08t7SdxtWso3oPLBOQs/xAHJqBaNgI/4U9/aFIQcSWkE/7Xd6IJ48xPfN8hynNfr0Cx9f1nidKY0DzyqNShgiNj/)

A port of [@tsh's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239668/9288).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](http://golly.sourceforge.net/Help/python.html) script in [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net/), 179 bytes

```python
from golly import*
new("")
setrule("TriTurmite_120010")
setcell(0,0,2)
run(int(getstring("")))
a=[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
show(str(sum(a[c%8]+a[c//8]for c in getcells(getrect())[2::3])))
```

Triangular Langton's ant is a built-in rule in Golly. But it simulates the triangular grid in a nontrivial way: two triangular cells are represented by one square cell. So I cannot simply use the `getpop` built-in.

Screenshot for input `1000`. Output is `106`:

[image: Screenshot for input 1000. Output is 106]

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>82 ...</s> 56 bytes

```ruby
a,*r=c=0;loop{p c+=(r!=r-=[a+=1i**(c*2/3)])?-1:(r<<a;1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P1FHq8g22dbAOic/v6C6QCFZ21ajSNG2SNc2OlHb1jBTS0sjWctI31gzVtNe19BKo8jGJtHaULP2/38A)

Saved a lot of bytes by stealing tsh's formula.

Comment: I just tried to remove the `&3` in your program, and looks like it still works. Maybe Ruby will not introduce floating point errors in `1i**n` where n is positive integer.

Comment: @tsh I was trying that too, I don't understand why it doesn't work in python. Or maybe it does?

Comment: Either that or the test cases are not big enough. In Python, you need `n>100` for the error to show up. EDIT Wait, there are no test cases...nvm

Comment: @tsh I think so, I tested with 100000 iterations and it still holds: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P1FHq8g22dbA2tAABPRKMnNTi6uTtW01ihRti3RtoxO1bQ0ztbQ0krWM9I01YzXtdQ2tNIpsbBKtDTVrrQsUiv7/BwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## TypeScript Types, 317 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type I<T,P=0,N=[1,0][P]>=T extends[N,...infer T]?T:[...T,P];type M<N,a=[[],[]],b=0,c=0,d=[],e=0,f=[],g=[1,0][c],h=a[0],i=a[1],j=[[I<h,c>,I<i,g>],[h,I<i,c>],[I<h,g>,i]][b]>=N extends d["length"]?f["length"]:j extends e?M<N,j,[1,2,0][b],g,[...d,0],Exclude<e,j>,I<f,1>>:M<N,j,[2,0,1][b],g,[...d,0],e|j,I<f>>
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACASQB4AVAGgAUBeABkoDlaBtARkvoF1XruAfLXKF0AD3DpEAE0ismlAHTLYiAGbpUhctwD85AFytliqvwDcuAoQCypBQEM2rbpReuARg0oBjb9LZXdG81QMp4Nk4eVh9XAAtaB1YeSlhEjlcAK2cyON8BSjJYcIFXVjyi-LLcktTuXg9BWiZRCSlZQmlWACIAGyl4cDjuvTUe-sRB4e4DTNbJGUhRXTsFTLdOACYuBtd4NxNpHcoAUTEfXoBXaXRSdEpMgrI1SnYBAQNVh7dtxnZd8IHZRHFLoAA+62e70w2HwRAASpdEDYHIgcBQBIRaIQAN6YQiEVgAaUIqkIAGt0DhkGptDNbBRiYJMABfGFWIjkehYwiI5Go9GsQiMAmcAnbAkAZkoBIALDLCABWBUANgVAHYFQAOBUATmZIAJhAAerpYdZyOweXyUWjSBwRewxewJexpYR2PKPcqPWqPZqPTqPfqBJhDQTTebOZtrUjbYLNiLNmLNhLNu7Nl7Nj7Nn7NgHNkHNiGw8AjZGOdpJbH+XbWJKRZKxZKJZL3ZKvZKfZK-ZKA5Kg5KS+GTWbK+RZTX4-bZSLZWLZRLZe7ZV7ZT7ZX7ZQHZUHZcOyxGx3DtIqpwL7YqRYqxYqJYr3YqvYqfYq-YqA4qg4qD+XjxaVXPOsVRFFUxRVCUVXdFUvRVH0VT9FUAxVIMVV-I9MCAA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

```
// Increment/decrement an integer stored as e.g. [0, 0] for 2, [1, 1, 1] for -3, and [] for 0
// Invoked as Inc<T> to increment, or Inc<T, 1> to decrement
type Inc<T, Pos = 0, Neg = [1, 0][Pos]> = T extends [Neg, ...infer T] ? T : [...T, Pos]

type Main<
  // The goal number of steps
  N,
  // Last position; stored using axial coordinates as two integers
  LastPos = [[], []],
  // The current axis; 0 | 1 | 2
  DirAxis = 0,
  // The current direction on the axis; 0 | 1
  DirSign = 0,
  // The number of steps taken so far
  Steps = [],
  // A union of all infected positions
  Infected = 0,
  // A tuple counting how many positions are infected
  InfectedCount = [],
  // The sign opposite DirSign
  OtherSign = [1, 0][DirSign],
  // Calculate the new position based on LastPos, DirAxis, and DirSign
  LastPos0 = LastPos[0],
  LastPos1 = LastPos[1],
  NewPos = [
    [Inc<LastPos0, DirSign>, Inc<LastPos1, OtherSign>],
    [LastPos0, Inc<LastPos1, DirSign>],
    [Inc<LastPos0, OtherSign>, LastPos1]
  ][DirAxis]
> =
  N extends Steps["length"]
    // If N == Steps, return InfectedCount
    ? InfectedCount["length"]
    // Otherwise,
    : NewPos extends Infected
      // If NewPos is in Infected,
      ? Main<
        N,
        NewPos,
        // Cycle DirAxis to the right
        [1, 2, 0][DirAxis],
        // Set DirSign to OtherSign
        OtherSign,
        // Add one to Steps
        [...Steps, 0],
        // Remove NewPos from Infected
        Exclude<Infected, NewPos>,
        // Decrement InfectedCount
        Inc<InfectedCount, 1>
      >
      // Otherwise,
      : Main<
        N,
        NewPos,
        // Cycle DirAxis to the left
        [2, 0, 1][DirAxis],
        // Set DirSign to OtherSign
        OtherSign,
        [...Steps, 0],
        // Add NewPos to Infected
        Infected | NewPos,
        // Increment InfectedCount
        Inc<InfectedCount>
      >
```

Comment: `N extends d["length"]` can be shortened to `d extends{length:N}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 144 bytes

```rust
let(mut x,mut p,mut c)=(vec![],[0,0],0);loop{print!("{}
",c);x.retain(|q|q!=&p);if c==x.len(){x.push(p)}c=x.len();p[c*2/3&1]+=1-2*(c/3&1)as i64}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLCoMwFAD3PUV0IXk2tdaWbkJOIi7kEWnAz1NjCcScPa2FbgZmFrNsq43dyIbWjByYj722fNgsc@Ig/Yig@FtjUjeiLkXZiBJkP03kaTGjTXjqwykVCNIVi7bHaZ/3OVEZgTQdQ6Vc0evv37uCtvXFCQL@m6Qa8@p6z27NWd0uVc7xEGhXZp6PEEP8AA)

Port of @loopy walt's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

```
(Clear@a;c=p=0;a@_=-1;Do[p+=I^⌊2/3(c+=a@p*=-1)⌋,#];c)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@1/DOSc1scgh0TrZtsDWwDrRId5W19DaJT@6QNvWM@5RT5eRvrFGsrZtokOBFlBG81FPt45yrHWyptp/oKKAosy8kui06LzYWB2F6jwdBQMdBSOD2tj/AA)

A port of [@tsh's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239668/9288).